# insert a newline before each 12 digit number js

Tags: javascript

I have a variable which store a very large string. this string has characters, spaces, tabs, numbers etc. I just want to add a new line before each 12 digits numbers in this string.

example:

Input :

```
# Time interval: from 12/25/2020 02:30  to 12/26/2020 03:30  UTC #  abc from 42026, def (pqr) | 34-03N | 074-24E | 2652 m 202012260300 AAXX 26034 42026 32596 50000 11050 21073 37300 49820 83520                    333 21065 59010 555 10212= 202012251200 AAXX 25124 42026 32596 60000 10000 21023 37300 49880 84520                    333 10034 58020=
202012250300 AAXX 25034 42026 32996 00000 11020 21045 37310 49965                    333 21056 58030 555 10212=
```

Output :

```
# Time interval: from 12/25/2020 02:30  to 12/26/2020 03:30  UTC #  abc from 42026, def (pqr) | 34-03N | 074-24E | 2652 m
202012260300 AAXX 26034 42026 32596 50000 11050 21073 37300 49820 83520                    333 21065 59010 555 10212=
202012251200 AAXX 25124 42026 32596 60000 10000 21023 37300 49880 84520                    333 10034 58020=
202012250300 AAXX 25034 42026 32996 00000 11020 21045 37310 49965                    333 21056 58030 555 10212=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
(\D)(\d{12})(\D)
```

to match a string of exactly 12 digits, and replace it with the matched string with a newline inserted:

```js
const str = '# Time interval: from 12/25/2020 02:30  to 12/26/2020 03:30  UTC #  abc from 42026, def (pqr) | 34-03N | 074-24E | 2652 m 202012260300 AAXX 26034 42026 32596 50000 11050 21073 37300 49820 83520                    333 21065 59010 555 10212= 202012251200 AAXX 25124 42026 32596 60000 10000 21023 37300 49880 84520                    333 10034 58020= 202012250300 AAXX 25034 42026 32996 00000 11020 21045 37310 49965                    333 21056 58030 555 10212='

console.log(str.replace(/(\D)(\d{12})(\D)/g, '$1\n$2$3'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do a regex search on the lookahead `(?=\b\d{12}\b)` and replace with a single newline:

```js
var input = "# Time interval: from 12/25/2020 02:30  to 12/26/2020 03:30  UTC #  abc from 42026, def (pqr) | 34-03N | 074-24E | 2652 m 202012260300 AAXX 26034 42026 32596 50000 11050 21073 37300 49820 83520                    333 21065 59010 555 10212= 202012251200 AAXX 25124 42026 32596 60000 10000 21023 37300 49880 84520                    333 10034 58020=\n202012250300 AAXX 25034 42026 32996 00000 11020 21045 37310 49965                    333 21056 58030 555 10212=";
var output = input.replace(/(?=\b\d{12}\b)/g, "\n");
console.log(input);
console.log(output);
```